# Create a X509 certificate with SANs

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

Is it possible to create X509 certificates with SANs (Subject Alternative Names) using `openssl` without touching a config file?

All the examples you find when searching Google about that topic (such as [here](http://apetec.com/support/GenerateSAN-CSR.htm) or [here](http://blog.icewolf.ch/archive/2012/01/10/openssl-certificate-signing-request-csr-for-san-certificates.aspx)) claim that you need to adjust or create a config file.

Does this work without, e.g. using a command-line switch and being asked for the SANs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a solution described in [this document](http://www.crsr.net/Notes/SSL.html) that requires you to modify a config file only once, using an environment variable, for example:

```
[ v3_req ]
subjectAltName=$ENV::ALTNAME
```

Note that this configuration file needs not be global. You can also use a local OpenSSL configuration file. For example using the `OPENSSL_CONF` environment variable (or the `-config` option):

```
export OPENSSL_CONF=./openssl.cnf
export ALTNAME="DNS:my.host.name,IP:10.0.0.1"
openssl req -new -x509 -key myhost-key.pem -out myhost-cert.pem -days 365
```